# Does YouTube premiere affect video exposure Algorithm (video recommendation)?

Tags: youtube

As you all know, you can literally see the video together with people for the first time with the premiere feature, and after watching the video, the video is uploaded. The question here is whether what happened at the time of the premiere(For example, the number of viewers, likes, or comments at the time of initial publication) affects the exposure algorithm of the video.